# JavaFX 2 : TableView : remove header + show grid when empty

Tags: css, javafx-2, tableview, columnheader

I have 2 questions about the TableView in Javafx2:

1)
Is it possible to hide the headers in your table?

2)
When the table is empty it just shows a white pane saying "No content in table.".
Is it possible to change this to display the default grid, even when the table is empty?

If possible, Id like a solution with CSS (javacode is also fine).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer to the first question is [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2321823). Note that you may hide the headers only after the table is rendered.

Answering your second question you may use following approach:

```
table.setPlaceholder(new Label("Placeholder"));
```

Instead of label you may add any `Node`.