# Hide nested column headers in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to be able to hide nested column headers in JavaFX. I have found some solutions which are all similar to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118872/how-to-hide-tableview-column-header-in-javafx-8)

The problem for me is that I only want to hide two nested columns, but I can only seem to hide all columns. Does anyone have any ideas of how to do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: May showing the 2 column values combined in one tablecolumn (without nested table columns) be an option for you?

Comment: The issue is both values represent an icon (set as graphic for that cell using a custom TableCell), one is Boolean and the other only shows if the string is not empty, so unfortunately it is not an option.